# How can I describe the set of homomorphisms and what is its cardinality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, universal-algebra

There are actually two questions here. Neither of these is a homework question.

Let $\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$ (not to be confused with the Hom functor) be the class$^0$ of homomorphisms between two structures (of the same signature) $\mathfrak{A}=(A,(f_i)_{i\in I})$ and $\mathfrak{B}=(B,(g_j)_{j\in J})$ $^1$. If the objects (domains) of $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ ($A$ and $B$, respectively) are sets, then $\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$ is a set.

**Question 1**

> Given two arbitrary structures $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ over
>   known sets ($A$ and $B$, respectively), what is the
>   cardinality of $\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$?

---

**My work:**

Using the product convention of functional analysis (a summary of which can be found [here](http://faculty.bard.edu/belk/math351/FunctionSpaces.pdf)), it is clear that...

$$\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})\subseteq\prod_{i\in A}B\cong B^{|A|}$$

...whence,...

$$|\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})|\le|B|^{|A|}$$

The lower bound of $|\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})|$ is obviously $0$, so $0\le|\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})|\le|B|^{|A|}$.$^2$ This is not much help on its own, though.

It is not generally true that the set of *functions* from $A$ to $B$ is the set of *homomorphisms* from $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathfrak{B}$; but I'm not sure how to reduce the set of functions to just the set of homomorphisms, which leads me to my second question.

---

**Question 2**

> Given two arbitrary structures $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ over
>   known sets ($A$ and $B$, respectively), characterize the set
>   $\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$.

I don't really have a good method for explicitly defining the set of homomorphisms between two structures - at least, not in a way that would let me  construct an explicit bijection from the set of homomorphisms to, say, an ordinal. It might be the case that the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ has a cardinality of $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ $^3$ while the set of homomorphisms has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$ - but I wouldn't know that unless I was able to enumerate the elements of $\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$ - which I can't do because I have no idea what it looks like.

---

**Footnotes**

$^0$ "class" here is meant roughly in the sense that it has been used in NBG, *Principia Mathematica* or the [metamath](http://us.metamath.org/index.html) language - e.g. a set is a class, a proper class is a class, a collection of proper classes is a class, etc. but a proper class is *not* a set, etc.

$^1$ I am ignorant of structures with an uncountable set of operations and/or relations, unless these are more common than I think, you can assume that $I$ and $J$ are countable.

$^2$ The smallest possible set containing all homomorphisms between arbitrary structures is the empty set, since there might not be *any* homomorphisms between them. $\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})=\emptyset\implies |\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})|=0$

$^3$ Depending on the choice of theory and the acceptance or rejection of the continuum hypothesis this may variously evaluate to $\mathfrak{c}$, $2^{\aleph_0}$, or $\aleph_1$. I'm leaving it as $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ because the details of this aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: "a collection of proper classes is a class" Wait, what? Also, in order to talk about homomorphisms between two structures, those structures have to have the same signature - that is, we need to have $I=J$ (and for $f_i$ and $g_i$ to have the same arity for each $i$).

Comment: Re: footnote 3, $\aleph_0{}^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ is provable in ZFC. Indeed, we'll always have $\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa$ for $\kappa$ infinite: clearly $2^\kappa\le\kappa^\kappa$, and conversely $\kappa^\kappa\le(2^\kappa)^\kappa=2^{\kappa\cdot \kappa}=2^\kappa$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber A convention which I've seen used more than once is to rank classes so that a set is a 0-class, a proper class is a 1-class, a class of proper classes is a 2-class, and so on. Despite it's casual use I've never seen this ranking formalized; a shame, really, since it isn't all that difficult. My personal scheme is built off of ordinal rank, using what is best described as a base-$\Omega$ number system (with $\Omega$ the class of all ordinals). In this system, a proper class is any class whose rank is $\alpha$, with $(1,0)\le\alpha<(1,0,0)$ ($(1,0)$ is the rank of $\Omega$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be your favorite polynomial with integer coefficients. Consider the rings $\mathfrak{A} = \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(p)$ and $\mathfrak{B} = \mathbb{Z}$. Then the set of ring homomorphisms $\text{Hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$ is in bijection with the set of integer solutions to $p = 0$. Explicitly, if $f\colon \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(p)\to \mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism, then $p(f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n)) = 0$, and for any tuple $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $p(a_1,\dots,a_n) = 0$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(p)\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x_i) = a_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

Now understanding the integer solutions to the Diophantine equation $p(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$ for various polynomials $p$ is a notoriously hard kind of problem in number theory (see e.g. Fermat's last theorem!). There's definitely no simple criterion for determining, for example, whether or not $\text{Hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})$ is finite, or even nonempty. In fact, in their solution to Hilbert's tenth problem, Martin Davis, Yuri Matiyasevich, Hilary Putnam and Julia Robinson proved that this problem is computationally undecidable.

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't have made the connection to Hilbert's tenth problem on my own. The specific example really helps! Now I'm curious, though. While the undecidability of Hilbert's tenth problem could be used to prove that $|\text{Hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})|$ can't be determined generally, I wonder if it might be possible for structures over finite sets?

Comment: Well, for finite structures, the answer is certainly computable: just enumerate all functions from $A$ to $B$ (there are finitely many), and check whether each one is a homomorphism. That describes an algorithm to count the number of homomorphisms, but there's no hope for a simple formula.

Comment: @R.Burton: Let K be the class of finite algebraic structures defined in the language of one binary operation. The problem of deciding if there is at least one homomorphism from A to B, for A, B in K, is in the complexity class NP. This decision problem is shown to be NP complete in Kevin Berg's paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.01817. So the problem is ``as hard as it can be'' even when restricted to finite structures.

Answer (score 3):

In general, **nothing can be said**, even if we're only looking at a signature consisting of a single unary function symbol $f$. For example, fixing an arbitrary cardinal $\kappa$:

- Let $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ each be the structure with domain your favorite set of cardinality $\kappa$ *(say, $\kappa$ itself)* and with $f$ interpreted as the identity. Then every map is a homomorphism.
- Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be as above, and let $\mathfrak{B}$ be any structure whatsoever in the same signature where $f$ is *never* the identity. Then there are no homomorphisms from $\mathfrak{A}$ to $\mathfrak{B}$ at all. (And by using *two* unary function symbols we can similarly whip up an example where there are no homomorphisms in either direction.)

So in general, there are no better bounds to be found.

Comment: Would it be possible to zero in on a criteria for determining whether or not $|\text{hom}(\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B})|$ is finite? Taking into account the particular functions in each, of course.

Comment: @R.Burton I can't imagine that being the case. The range of possible structures is so broad that I don't think there's anything useful to be said here without zooming in *drastically* (e.g. looking specifically at groups).